# Does GAE provides access to use sockets?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Is there a way I can use sockets in Google Applications Engine?
I was building an example but whenever I try to use the sockets module the console reports:

```
**'module' object has no attribute 'socket'.**
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it does not support sockets.

Have a look at the channel API:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/

> The Channel API creates a persistent connection between your application and Google servers, allowing your application to send messages to JavaScript clients in real time without the use of polling

[Google app engine,sockets are disabled,what it means](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459371/google-app-engine-sockets-are-disabled-what-it-means)

What is/is not supported:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/general#libraries

EDIT: Socket support in preview now: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/sockets/

Answer (score 4):

The answer as of 09/2012 is no. But, ..

if you are interested in outbound sockets, consider joining the early tester program for access to outbound socket functionality in App Engine:
https://groups.google.com/d/topic/google-appengine/m1x6sDhqx1o/discussion